# How do you make a module-level function NOT readonly?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, readonly, monkeypatching

Suppose you have a Typescript module that looks like this:

```
// mymodule.ts

export function aFunction () {
    console.log('Howdie Doody');
}

// End of module
```

If I import this into a second module, I am unable to reassign what `aFunction` does. That is, if I do:

```
// secondModule.ts

import * as firstModule from 'mymodule.ts`;

firstModule.aFunction = () => { console.log('New message!') } 

// "Cannot assign to 'aFunction' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)
```

How do I make `aFunction` not read only so that I can reassign it?

I want to do this so that I easily test functions that *use* `aFunction`

Comment: @Dai fixed the code. Removing `const` doesn't fix the problem though

Comment: `export aFunction ()` isn't valid - it should be either `export function aFunction() {`, 
 `export aFunction = function() {`, or `export aFunction = () => {`

Comment: @Dai edited. Problem is still there though

Answer (score 0):

[In ES6, imports are live read-only views on exported values](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values)

As I understand it es6 import designed to be readonly and you have to use other patterns to change the `aFunction` on fly

> In contrast to CommonJS, imports are views on exported values. In other words, every import is a live connection to the exported data. **Imports are read-only**:
>
> Unqualified imports (import x from 'foo') are like const-declared variables.
> The properties of a module object foo (import * as foo from 'foo') are **like** the properties of **a frozen object**.